# Selenium action chains to click inside silverlight plugin object in a page

Tags: python, silverlight, selenium

Currently trying to click a button inside of a silverlight web app, and yes I know beforehand silverlight is not supported but I think at least it worth a try with the action chain module. Here is the best I could come up with until now:

```
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('plugin.default.state', 2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get('http://www.trypython.org')
time.sleep(8)
sldiv = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="silverlightControlHost"]')
builder = ActionChains(driver)
builder.move_to_element_with_offset(sldiv, 372, 44)
builder.click()
```

IT is not clicking, or at least not in the expected coordinates (where the button is). Will I get away with this? if so, will I be able to type some text after clicking inside a textbox?

- Do not even mention silverlight-selenium outdated project

Comment: I think you answered your own question: "IT is not clicking". Selenium needs a browser DOM. Browser plugins, such as Silverlight, have no DOM. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

Comment: @SiKing Well I am not completely sure about actions chains to actually use the DOM as the element locator would do, but if what you said is true then there is no hope I guess

Comment: There is *always* hope! :) If you're on Windows, you could try [tag:AutoIt]. It can be easily combined with Selenium. It will even work with Java, using [tag:JNA] or [tag:JNI].